# This subscription is at capacity for Total Regional Cores on this location

Tags: azure

I am trying to create new images in Azure and I get this message: “This subscription is at capacity for Total Regional Cores on this location. This subscripton is using all 20 Total Regional Cores available.”

Does this mean I reached to the capacity of my license or there is a technical limitation? Is there any way I can add more VMs? The only requirement I have is those VM images should be able to communicate with each other internally.

Thanks for everyone's help.
Harry

Comment: You need to open a (free) billing ticket and ask for additional resources for your subscription. But... it's off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

These are safeguards to prevent people from making provisioning errors.  Contact support to ask them to add more capacity to your subscription.  Unless there's a hardware limitation or something like that, they'll be more then happy to provide you with more resources.